# Index on devise instead of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm using Devise, but I see I need to use `rails generate devise MODEL` which I use. But is there a way to just have `/sign_in` and so fourth, instead of `/MODEL/sign_in`?

`rails generate devise`?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`devise_for`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for) and look for `path` option.  Using `devise_for :model, path: '/'` in your `config/routes.rb` should solve your issue.

Comment: Would I do this after creating the model? Also why can I just do `rails generate devise u`? It seems that you need 2 characters @vee

Comment: Yes, if your model is going to be called say `user` then you would use the command `rails generate devise user`.  By default you'll get `/users/sign_in` after devise generator has been run.  So you'd modify the entry in `config/routes.rb` to `devise_for :users, path: '/'`.

Comment: Please consider going through this article: [`Getting started`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add path option in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
                                            registrations: "users/registrations",
                                            sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

and now routes:

```
                   user_password POST       /password(.:format)                                                devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET        /password/new(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET        /password/edit(.:format)                                           devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH      /password(.:format)                                                devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT        /password(.:format)                                                devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET        /cancel(.:format)                                                  users/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST       /                                                                  users/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET        /sign_up(.:format)                                                 users/registrations#new
```

instead:

```
                   user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                                          devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)                                     devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH      /users/password(.:format)                                          devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT        /users/password(.:format)                                          devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                                            users/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                                                   users/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                                           users/registrations#new
```